# YUI datatable key events

Tags: javascript, yui

I am using a yui scroll-able data table.  And i want to add a functionality that when i click down arrow key it will show "Next",  and on up arrow key "Previous".

```
myDataTable.subscribe("keydownEvent", function (oArgs) 
{
alert("Next");
}); 

myDataTable.subscribe("keyupEvent", function (oArgs) 
{
alert("Previous");
});
```

I am not sure about the events i have to call. Can anyone help me out. As per my understanding i have to apply a function using a key press event but not sure how to??

Answer (score 0):

you need to use something like this:

```
myDataTable.subscribe('cellClickEvent',function(ev) {
    var target = YAHOO.util.Event.getTarget(ev);
    var column = myDataTable.getColumn(target);
    if (column.key == 'delete') {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            myDataTable.deleteRow(target);
        }
    } else {
        myDataTable.onEventShowCellEditor(ev);
    }
});
```

and http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/09/26/satyam-datatable-2/

Comment: This is pagination functionality. What i want is a table has 15 record and initially first is selected. so when i click down arrow key from keyboard, an alert will open like ("Next")

Comment: try looking in the link in answer for section Adding editors there it is mentioned to add event-listeners.